# passing content value through intent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

how do i pass this content value through an intent to another class/view

this is my code for the content values on my Main Activity:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("entry", returnedEntry);
                cv.put("def", returnedDefinition);

                Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewDefinition.class);
                i.putExtra("name", cv);
                startActivity(i);
```

I wanna know what to write to the class where i would pass the content values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString("key","value you need to retrieve in another activity");
b.putString("name","arjun");
Intent i=new Intent(ctx,Youractivityname.class);
i.putExtras(b); 
StartActiviyt(i);
```

**UPDATE**

```
String value = bundle.getString("key");
String name = bundle.getString("name");
```

create new `contentvalues` with the above value

Comment: how will i retrieve the values for the next class? can you please write it down? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i= getIntent();
    String message = i.getStringExtra(LastActivity.name);

    TextView textView = new TextView (this);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the procedure.

Create a new Intent with bundle and start the activity.

```
Intent i= new Intent(context,ActivityName.Class);
i.putExtra("key",mystring);
startActiivty(i);
```

Take the bundle like this in new Activity inside onCreate

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) 
{
 String value = extras.getString("key");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
ContentValues o = (ContentValues) intent.getExtras().get("name");
if ( o != null)
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + o.getAsFloat("entry"));
```